# Fitting GLMM using lme4 package, fitting algorithm

Tags: likelihood, glmm, fitting, laplace-approximation

I'm a little confused here. So I'm using glmm model to fit user/item interaction. If user #12 liked movie #15 it's 1 otherwise it's 0. Here is my model:

```r
model <- glmer(y ~ x - 1 + (1 | users) + (1 | items), family=binomial, data = data, control=control, nAGQ=nAGQ)
```

My question is about the nAGQ. Here is the explanation:

integer scalar - the number of points per axis for evaluating the adaptive GaussHermite approximation to the log-likelihood. Defaults to 1, corresponding to the Laplace approximation. Values greater than 1 produce greater accuracy in the evaluation of the log-likelihood at the expense of speed. A value of zero uses a faster but less exact form of parameter estimation for GLMMs by optimizing the random effects and the fixed-effects coefficients in the penalized iteratively reweighted least squares step. (See Details.)

I am not quite sure about the place of PIRLS. I thought we were optimizing the likelihood using Quasi-likelihood or Laplace approximation. Can you explain this?